# How to search GitHub API for followers between two values?

Tags: github-api

Something like this doesn't work:

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=followers:>2500+followers:<3000
```

Is there any way to do this, perhaps with the GraphQL API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data between two values, you can use .. between the two values. See the link
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=followers:2501..2999